Override docker compose from shell script
I have a docker compose file
    version: '3.3'
    services:
      test:
        volumes:
            - $WORKSPACE:$WORKSPACE
            - $HOME:$HOME
        environment:
            - HOME=$HOME
        working_dir: $WORKING_DIR
        image: $BUILD_IMAGE
        command: bash $WORKSPACE/somescript.sh

I have shell script where I want to override the values.
My script-> test.sh
HOME=`pwd`
WORKSPACE=/tmp/
BUILD_IMAGE=someimage
docker stack deploy --compose-file  compose.yml test

How to override the value.

You have to put the variables to override on the same docker command line in order to modify then docker process environment:
HOME=`pwd` WORKSPACE=/tmp/ BUILD_IMAGE=someimage docker stack deploy --compose-file compose.yml test

or if you prefer (one per line with backslashes):
HOME=`pwd` \
WORKSPACE=/tmp/ \
BUILD_IMAGE=someimage \
docker stack deploy --compose-file compose.yml test

